# Bootstrap click does not work on ASP.NET Webform site after upgrading NuGet packages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms, nuget-package

If I update the NuGet packages listed in the attached image (namely, AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap and AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery, bootstrap v3.3.7, jQuery v3.1.0) in Visual Studio Community 2015, then the generated Web site (based on ASP.NET Webform) is broken because none Bootstrap element will react after being clicked, for example, when the window is reduced, clicking on the Boostrap menu does not display the different items, clicking on a dropdown list does display the items in the list... It works if I don't update to those new NuGet packages. The first version of the Web site has been created with the ASP.NET WebForms site and works but uses an old version of Boostrap and jQuery.

How to update to jQuery v3.1.0 and Bootstrap 3+ in Visual Studio Community 2015 and still be able to click on those Boostrap elements in the generated Web site?

[NuGet packages that break clicking on the Bootstrap elements when updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdbHt.png)

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you running now? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: After upgrading Visual Studio, creating a new MVC 5 project and updating all NuGet packages, including jQuery and Bootstrap, it still worked. So there is no problem anymore on my side.